# How do I access each element in list in for-loop operations?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am looping through this list and don't understand why `print(d)` returns each number in `seed` but assigning `i["seed"] = d` assigns the last element of `seed`.

How do I access each element in `seed` for operations other than `print()`?

```
res = []
seed = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
i = {}
for d in seed:
    print(d)
    i["seed"] = d
    res.append(i)
print(res)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `i["seed"]=d` supposed to be doing?

Comment: its adding the key seed to the dict, (which is being overridden)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is where you are defining i. I *think* you intended to have a dictionary object named i that has  single attribute named "seed". and you want to add those dictionaries to res.

In actual fact you only have one dictionary called i and you just update the value in it every time through the loop.

try this:

```
res = []
seed = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for d in seed:
    i = {}
    print(d)
    i["seed"] = d
    res.append(i)
print(res)
```

That will create a new instance of i for each loop, and you should get the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is there is only one object `i`, and you're replacing its value every time in the loop.  By the last iteration your (one instance) of i has its value set to the last item you assigned it to.  Each time you append to `res`, you're basically appending the a pointer to the same object (so you end up with 9 pointers pointing to the same object when your loop is finished).

```
res = []
seed = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
i = {}
for d in seed:
    print(d)
    i["seed"] = d  # this gets replaced every time through your loop!
    res.append(i.copy())  # need to copy `i`, or else we're updating the same instance
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, it is because thew value of seed is being overwritten, as shown here:

```
>>> p = {'t':'H'}
>>> p['t'] = 'k'
>>> p
{'t': 'k'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces `{}` in python represent [dictionaries](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) which works based on a key and value. Each time you iterate through your loop you overwrite the key: 'seed' with the current value of the list seed. So by the time the loop ends the last value of the list seed is the current value of seed in the dictionary i.